# Let A ⊂ R be a bounded set. Prove that there is n ∈ N such that A ⊂ [−n, n].

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A ⊂ \mathbb R$ be a bounded set. Prove that there is $n ∈ \mathbb N$ such that $A ⊂ [−n, n]$.

I know to use the Archimedean Axiom to prove the n the upper bound.I'm just having trouble proving the part pertaining to the -n.Here's what I have so far.

"Let $z ∈ \mathbb R$ and define a set A  n ∈ N : n ≤ z as the set of all natural numbers
less than or equal to z. If A is empty, then the result follows immediately. If A is not empty,
then A is bounded above by z and hence by the completeness axiom, A has a least upper
bound, say . Since  is the least upper bound, it follows that  − 1 is not an upper bound
for A so there exists some m ∈ A with  − 1  m. But in that case,   m  1, which is to say
m  1 is a natural number not belonging to A (a natural number larger than z ). This proves
the result. Notice that the proof of the Archimedean property is quite similar to the proof in
problem 1.7. This is because if there were some real number z for which the Archimedean
property failed, then this z would be an upper bound for the natural numbers. Then the
11
onexistence of infinite reals is equivalent to the nonexistence of an upper bound for the
natural numbers."

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks guys.

Comment: Consider $B=\{|x|\mid x\in A\}$.

Answer (score 3):

You are making this problem harder than it needs to be.  Since $A$ is bounded, there is an $M\in\Bbb R^+$ such that $A\subseteq [-M,M]$.  By the Archimedean property, there is an $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $M<N$ and hence $A\subseteq [-N,N]$.

Comment: "You are making this problem harder than it needs to be." - Wish I had a stamp that said this when I was grading for undergrad real analysis...

Comment: Yeah. That probably would have been handy. :)

Answer (score 0):

$Α$ is bounded, so from the Axiom of Completeness there exist $l, u\in \Bbb R$, such that $l:=infA, u:=supA$. That is $\forall a\in A: l\leq a\leq u$ (1). Set $max\{|[l]|,|[u]+1|\}:=n\in \Bbb N$ (2), where $[x]$ the integer part of real number $x$ and $[x]\leq x\leq [x]+1$. From (1), (2) and basic theory of inequalities we get $\forall a\in A: -n\leq -|[l]|\leq [l]\leq l\leq a\leq u\leq [u]+1\leq |[u]+1|\leq n$, so, if $a\in A$, then $a\in [-n,n]$, which means that $A\subseteq [-n,n]$.

Comment: I think this is the best approach, because it is producted immediately by an Axiom.